# How to pass keyfile as argument in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-bigquery, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using [the bigQuery gem](https://github.com/abronte/BigQuery/) in my project. I initialize it with options client_id, service_email, key, project_id, and dataset. I have my .p12 file from Google that I want to pass in but I'm not sure where to put the file in my Rails project - I tried putting it in the same directory as my config file and passing the relative path name, but I'm getting an invalid passphrase error. Specifically, [line 10](https://github.com/abronte/BigQuery/blob/master/lib/bigquery.rb) is throwing an error when load_key is being called:

```
key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(
  opts['key'],
  "notasecret"
)
```

So clearly it's not loading the key file correctly. I'm terrible at Rails asset control - where should I put my keyfile and what pathname should I pass in my options hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place the keyfile into the config directory, then do the following:

```
opts['key'] = Rails.root.join('config','nameofkeyfile.p12').to_s
```

You don't want the key to be in a location that your application will serve up to the public, so config sounds like a good location to me.

You can experiment with the block you have above in the Rails console:

```
# run `rails c` then
keypath = Rails.root.join('config','nameofkeyfile.p12').to_s
key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(keypath, "notasecret")
```

Looking at the [Google::APIClient documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/APIClient/PKCS12), I see `load_key` is deprecated. They recommend using `Google::APIClient::KeyUtils` instead.

```
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(keyfile, "notasecret")
```

As for a quick overview of the Rails asset pipeline, see [here](http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/04/24/asset-pipeline-for-dummies/). (Please pardon the "for dummies" part of that url, it appears to be good, quick info.)

Comment: excuse my noobness but where did you get the key, and where did you put it?

Comment: @dangalg - I'm not completely sure but from a quick look it appears that you can generate a key [with these instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation). There might be different methods for each app. (I'm more familiar with the ruby side than the actual Google::APIClient.) As to where to put it, in this case it goes in rails app's config directory, so 'config/nameofkeyfile.p12'. HTH